# ASP.net MVC 4 display image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im displaying an image on my page like so

```
 <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PhotoDisplay)" />
```

my model

```
 public byte[] PhotoDisplay { get; set; }
```

However PhotoDisplay may not have an image so may returns null so im getting an error

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null."

How what the best way to handle this, example would be great.

Comment: `@if(Model.PhotoDisplay != null) { <img src="data:image.....`

Comment: Thanks, any better way to handle it controller side?

Comment: "Controller side" all you can do is to add a "default" empty image if `PhotoDisplay` is `null`

Comment: Just a random thought: create a 1x1 transparent image and, on the server side, check whether your `PhotoDisplay` has any value. If not, just return the transparent pixel (i.e it's base64 value).

Comment: `Model.PhotoDisplay = Model.PhptoDisplay ?? System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(emptyImagePath)` may be?

Answer (score 1):

You could use shared templates to do this.

You could annotate your byte array with something like

```
[UIHint("BytePhoto")]
public byte[] PhotoDisplay { get; set; }
```

and create a new file called `BytePhoto.cstml` in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/`

That file contents should look something like this

```
@model byte[]
@if (Model != null)
{
   <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model)" />
} else {
   <b>No image to display</b>
}
```

Then you could call this display template using `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhotoDisplay)` in your Razor files rather than `<img src="data:image; base64, @System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PhotoDisplay)" />`.

If this is something you might do a lot you could go one step further and create a class that would encapsulate the byte array called something like `BytePhoto`.  Then you would not need the UIHint at all and the Razor markup would just work using the Display Templates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess putting nullable might help you as shown below :-

```
public byte[]? PhotoDisplay { get; set; }
```

or you can even code as below :-

```
[Column(TypeName = "image")]
public byte[] PhotoDisplay { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks, any better way to handle it controller side?

There is only one option, if you're passing from controller `byte[] PhotoDisplay`, you have to validate that field on front side - as Stephen Muecke wrote in comment:

```
@if(Model.PhotoDisplay != null) 
{ 
    <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PhotoDisplay)" />
}
else
{
    // some message
}
```

Otherwise, you can also do something like this at controller side:

```
private byte[] _photoDisplay
public byte[] PhotoDisplay { 
   get{ 
       return _photoDisplay!=null?_photoDisplay:new byte[1]; 
   } 
   set
   {
      _photoDisplay = value; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to keep your markup as simple as possible, you can do this:

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PhotoDisplay ?? new byte[0])" onerror="this.src='';" />
```

What this essentially does is if your `Mode.PhotoDisplay` proeprty is null, it passes in an empty `byte` array to the `System.Convert.ToBase64String` method. The method will then return an empty string.

At this point, the browser will display some sort of "broken image" icon since the `src` attribute will no longer be valid. Because it is no longer valid, the `onerror` handler will be invoked. I am simply setting the `src` attribute to an empty string. You can handle it differently if you'd like (e.g. set the `src` to a URL, hide the tag completely, etc.).